# Indexing column with REPLACE function in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, indexing, myisam

May be a silly question to ask.

I need to use this a lot in both *join* and *where*:

```
REPLACE(table_a.column_1, '-', '') = REPLACE(table_b.column_2, '-', '')
```

since bit data inconsistency from other companies' system

Is that possible or any other database type can have index of a column with REPLACE function? eg:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_a` ADD INDEX ( REPLACE(`column_1`, '-', '') ) ;
```

Database Type: MyISAM

Comment: Why is it that `table_a.column_1 = table_b.column_2` would not work here?

Comment: I read it somewhere that using a Funtion on variable doesn't use index nor you can create index on function, as functions output is not determined, So, my answer is no

Comment: @AshwinMukhija maybe his data has more - from other company db then they have...

Comment: @Sumit Gupta yup exactly, tables are from different companies, the trigger suggested by Sylvain will do the ticks, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in MySQL.

If you want to format some value to speed-up index search, you will probably have to use some trigger. As a matter of fact, I answered almost the same question this morning: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18047511/2363712 for a similar example.

In your case, that would lead to something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a`(`column_1` VARCHAR(255), ... ,
                       `column_1_fmt` VARCHAR(255),
                       INDEX(`column_1_fmt`));

CREATE TRIGGER ins_table_a BEFORE INSERT ON `table_a`
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.`column_1_fmt` = REPLACE(NEW.column_1, '-', '');

CREATE TRIGGER upd_table_a BEFORE UPDATE ON `table_a`
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.`column_1_fmt` = REPLACE(NEW.column_1, '-', '');
```

Now you will use `column_1_fmt` to search for values/join on values having the required format.

---

Concerning *your* special need (removing *dashes* -- from some kind of serial/reference number?). Maybe you should reverse the problem. Store those value as canonical form (no dash). And add required dashes at `SELECT` time.